# Short PHP code to produce hours options

Tags: php, select

Is there a shorter way to produce this html code with PHP?

Basically it's just a select input with hours of work options (every 30 minutes is a another option).

```
<select>
<option value="0" selected="selected" >From:</option>
<option value="8:00" >8:00</option>
<option value="8:30" >8:30</option>
<option value="9:00" >9:00</option>
<option value="9:30" >9:30</option>
<option value="10:00" >10:00</option>
<option value="10:30" >10:30</option>
<option value="11:00" >11:00</option>
<option value="11:30" >11:30</option>
<option value="12:00" >12:00</option>
<option value="12:30" >12:30</option>
<option value="13:00" >13:00</option>
<option value="13:30" >13:30</option>

... And so on up to 7:30 ...

<option value="7:30" >7:30</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sure. Use a loop and http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php to add 30 minutes for each iteration.

Comment: Yes, there is a shorter way. What have you tried?

Comment: I didn't try anything yet, i'm don't use php a lot and don't even know where to start, but i will to understand and check the first comment idea from @ceejayoz

Comment: Btw - Some ice coffee can make you cooler :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. probably a little smaller.

```
while ($o <= 47) {
    $date = new DateTime("08:00:00");
    $date->add(new DateInterval("PT".($o*30)."M"));
    echo '<option value="'. $date->format('H:i') .'" >'. $date->format('H:i') .'</option>';
    $o ++;
}
```

The loop is fourty seven as there's 24*2 increments minus one hour.

will output the following:

```html
<select>
<option value="08:00" >08:00</option><option value="08:30" >08:30</option><option value="09:00" >09:00</option><option value="09:30" >09:30</option><option value="10:00" >10:00</option><option value="10:30" >10:30</option><option value="11:00" >11:00</option><option value="11:30" >11:30</option><option value="12:00" >12:00</option><option value="12:30" >12:30</option><option value="13:00" >13:00</option><option value="13:30" >13:30</option><option value="14:00" >14:00</option><option value="14:30" >14:30</option><option value="15:00" >15:00</option><option value="15:30" >15:30</option><option value="16:00" >16:00</option><option value="16:30" >16:30</option><option value="17:00" >17:00</option><option value="17:30" >17:30</option><option value="18:00" >18:00</option><option value="18:30" >18:30</option><option value="19:00" >19:00</option><option value="19:30" >19:30</option><option value="20:00" >20:00</option><option value="20:30" >20:30</option><option value="21:00" >21:00</option><option value="21:30" >21:30</option><option value="22:00" >22:00</option><option value="22:30" >22:30</option><option value="23:00" >23:00</option><option value="23:30" >23:30</option><option value="00:00" >00:00</option><option value="00:30" >00:30</option><option value="01:00" >01:00</option><option value="01:30" >01:30</option><option value="02:00" >02:00</option><option value="02:30" >02:30</option><option value="03:00" >03:00</option><option value="03:30" >03:30</option><option value="04:00" >04:00</option><option value="04:30" >04:30</option><option value="05:00" >05:00</option><option value="05:30" >05:30</option><option value="06:00" >06:00</option><option value="06:30" >06:30</option><option value="07:00" >07:00</option><option value="07:30" >07:30</option></select>
```

Comment: Thanks! Great! short and working :) i would there's a shorter way but i can't seam to get on :) any way that's great enough for now, thank you very much.

Comment: BTW - if one uses this code and wants to reuse the same hours list a few times in a form you can add `ob_start();` before the `while`, then `$workHours = ob_get_clean();` after the end of the loop. and then `echo $workHours` where ever you want to use this options in a select's options list.

Answer (score 1):

For fun:

```
foreach(range(strtotime('8:00'), strtotime('19:30'), 1800) as $time) {
    $val = date('g:i', $time);
    echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</option>';
}
```

- Create a range of times in 30 minute increments (1800 seconds)
- Loop this range and convert the time into the correct format
- Use this formatted time in your options

If you run this across a date/time in which daylight savings time is changed then it will not function correctly.  You could alleviate this by setting to a timezone that does not have daylight savings time:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: Ah, I upvoted this as he/she accepted my somewhat 'longer and more complicated' version over this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop to echo `<option>` tag and generating time like this.

```
<select>
<option value="0" selected="selected" >From:</option>
<?
    $hour = 7;
    $min = 30;
    for ($x=0;$x < 48;$x++) {
        if ($min < 30) {
            $min += 30;
        } else {
            if ($hour < 24) {
                $min = 0;
                $hour += 1;
            } else {
                $hour = 1;
                $min = 0;
            }
        }
        $hour = sprintf("%02d", $hour);
        $min = sprintf("%02d", $min);
        echo '<option value="'.$hour.':'.$min.'">'.$hour.':'.$min.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

**Note 1**: It is not tested and may not work properly.
**Note 2**: I also know, *"it's not short!"*

## Update

I added leading zero before single digit numbers to match your format.

Comment: That's a great direction for me, but i will try to see if it's possible to make it shorter.

Comment: @Nori Thanks, I also trying to make it shorter as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<?php
$start = 8 * 60 * 60;
$step = 30 * 60;

$opts = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $time = date('H:i', $start + $i * $step);
$opt = <<<OPT
<option value="{$time}">{$time}</option>
OPT;
    $opts .= $opt;
}

echo <<<OPTS
<select>
<option value="0" selected="selected" >From:</option>
{$opts}
</select>
OPTS;
```